# Sync files between two different folders on a single Mac

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, folders, git

I am looking for a solution to sync files within different folders on a single Mac.

The files are tracked under Git version control system, so I can't use aliases.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), so can you describe in more details which basic problem you are trying to solve here (without already making assumptions about a sync being the solution)?

Answer (score 1):

Since the files are under Git version control, you can simply add the second folder as a remote repository.

Once done, you can sync the files between the two by performing Git Pull and Push operations.

However, the only drawback is that the sync will have to be performed manually.

Comment: One can always set up a crontab/launchd entry to run `git pull` regularly.

Answer (score 1):

If the git solution does not work for you Linux has you covered.

For folder syncing use [rsync -avP —delete —exclude=‘excludeDir’ /path/source /path/dest](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/show-progress-during-file-transfer/)
or 
[mirror](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/lftp-mirror-example/)
And for automatic operation use the scheduler [crontab](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)

Comment: Linux really has nothing to do with this as `rsync` is a part of macOS and the macOS way to schedule things is `launchd` not `crontab`. Yes, `crontab` is still available but is no longer  really a part of Apple's roadmap for such events.